# .htaccess 500 Internal error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know this is a common problem for mis formatted code, but the problem I'm getting is I have a .htaccess file with some 'deny from' IP lines up there on site and it's working fine.

When I add a new line and upload I get the 500 error. If I delete that line so it's back to what it was and upload, I still the 500 error. Only solution seems to delete the .htaccess all together.

Strangely though, If I leave it a day or two I can re-upload that same file and get no 500 error.

Comment: What is the content of your .htaccess? Is it possible that it's not getting the correct CHMOD value?

Comment: Check the server’s error log.

Comment: The content is:

    `order allow,deny
    deny from 91.232.96.8
    deny from 195.190.13.142
    deny from 178.158.221.73
    deny from 173.199.115.51
    deny from 188.143.234.127
    deny from 173.199.120.83
    deny from 222.80.67.130
    deny from 213.238.175.10
    deny from 216.152.249.242
    deny from 216.151.137.35
    deny from 91.232.96.8
    allow from all`

and permissions are set 644.

Comment: That would be layed out in a nice code block, but doesn't seem possible on a Mac in Safari or Chrome!